# PHP exec on local script

Tags: php, linux, shell

Hello i have a PHP script, and its added to cron, it is possible to execute from this script shell command (with exec() or something) without enabling it on php.ini? I don't want to enable exec on my site

Comment: You can use different `php.ini` files to execute php via apacha and cli. You can also specify a specific `ini`-file (to be used when running this specific cronjob) - check parameter `-c`. Running shell commands without enabling them won't work.

Answer (score 0):

It's called PHP CLI, check [here](http://php.net/manual/en/features.commandline.php)

Usually when you install `php`, there's option to install `php_cli` too.
So long you can run `php` on shell prompt, then it can work.

Open bash (or other shell), try this:

```
php -v
```

If the version printed, then it's working.

Then you can

```
php -f phpfile
```

or put

```
#!/usr/bin/php
```

At the beginning of your php file as a line, and `chmod +x file.php`, and then

```
./file.php
#or
/path/to/file.php
```

to run it.
(Note `/usr/bin/php` is the usual place of `php` executable, it might change, eg in unix is ually `/bin/php`. Use `whereis php` to check its place.)